# Tomcat ClassNotFoundException for Listener

Tags: java, tomcat, classnotfoundexception

I have a listener in the package `nl.hu.tho6.listener` called `ContextListener`. When deploying tomcat gives a `SEVERE: Error listenerStart` error. Digging around in the `localhost` log I founc out that tomcat throws a `ClassNotFoundException` for the listener class.

The `web.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>nl.hu.tho6.listener.ContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

I ave no clue whatsoever about what's going wrong. I'ts obvious tomcat can't find the class but the mapping is right. Could it have something to do with the fact that i'm using IntelliJ?

EDIT:

Entire Exception:

```
jan 22, 2015 1:51:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class nl.hu.tho6.listener.ContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nl.hu.tho6.listener.ContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1286)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:694)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:612)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you show the whole exception? Are you running tomcat insinde IntelliJ or separately?

Comment: seperately, the git repository for the project is located [here](https://github.com/zaans2/THO6)

Comment: Where is the class located (jar?)

Comment: @maslan how do you mean? after compiling the class is in `war/WEB-INF/classes/production/THO6/nl/hu/tho6/listener/` and when I run the ANT build script it packages the war file into `THO6.war` which it then deploys to the tomcat server

Comment: Should the listener class then be on folder `war/WEB-INF/classes/nl/hu/tho6/listener/` ?

Comment: @ikettu that was it, output of the compiler in intellij wasn't to the right path

Comment: @ikettu yeah, it should not be in "production"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments the file is on wrong folder.
Class should be in `war/WEB-INF/classes/nl/hu/tho6/listener/` not in `war/WEB-INF/classes/production/THO6/nl/hu/tho6/listener/`

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the error message to be correct, unless you have reason to believe otherwise?

I would look in the war file and check whether the class is there, e.g:

```
jar -tf mywebapp.war | grep ContextListener
```

If it isn't shown then check your build process - you haven't mentioned whether you're using ant, maven or something else, but that would be where to start.

Comment: The ContextListener is there, the path that the compiler was outputting to was wrong. I'm using ant but before I run that i have to compile manually because ant won't do that automatically for some reason in IntelliJ.

Comment: @LiamdeHaas
Maybe You should check the ant, so it'd do this for You?

Comment: @maslan any suggestions to how? don't know much about ant

Comment: Ok, so tell me how do You compile Your sources and build war?